# Using alias in ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, file-geodatabase, fields-attributes, alias

I am doing this:

Access a few columns from a file geodatabase.

```
arcpy.env.workspace = path
datasetList = arcpy.ListTables("tableA") # Here putting the name of the table

 for dataset in datasetList:
      with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(dataset, ["tablename","query"]) as cur:
           for row in cur:
               print row[0]


RuntimeError: A column was specified that does not exist
```

This works fine if it reads from a certain table. If I put another table with the same mentioned columns as aliases but different names it gives the error. If aliases can't be used here then what is the usability because now the table has to be recreated with the correct names. It is a problem that it doesn't allow you to rename the columns.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

List the field names using their aliases:

```
fieldnames = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(dataset) if f.aliasName in ["tablename","query"]]
```

And then use `fieldnames` in cursor